# How can I get PDVisibleSigProperties to write the signature on the 3 page into the signature box

Tags: java, digital-signature, pdfbox

I am working with the pdfbox example signature CreateVisableSignature and I would like the code to write the image of the signature into a signature field called "ApplicantSignature" on the third page.

Can someone give a clue as to why it writes the signature in the upper left corner of the first page?

Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException,
        FileNotFoundException, IOException, COSVisitorException,
        SignatureException {

    if (args.length != 4) {
        usage();
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        File ksFile = new File(args[0]);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", provider);
        char[] pin = args[1].toCharArray();
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(ksFile), pin);
        File document = new File(args[2]);
        CreateVisibleSignature signing = new CreateVisibleSignature(
                keystore, pin.clone());
        String jpgFile = CreateVisibleSignature.convertPngToJpeg( args[3] );
        FileInputStream image = new FileInputStream( jpgFile );
        PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(
                args[2], image, 1);
        visibleSig.xAxis(0).yAxis(0).zoom(-75)
                .signatureFieldName("ApplicantSignature");
        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();
        signatureProperties.signerName("name").signerLocation("location")
                .signatureReason("Security").preferredSize(0).page(3)
                .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                .buildSignature();
        signing.signPDF(document, signatureProperties);
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
    PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(
                args[2], image, 3);
        visibleSig.xAxis(0).yAxis(0).zoom(-75)
                .signatureFieldName("ApplicantSignature");
        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();
        signatureProperties.signerName("name").signerLocation("location")
                .signatureReason("Security").preferredSize(0).page(1)
                .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                .buildSignature();
```

And I have tried:

```
    PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(
                args[2], image, 3);
        visibleSig.xAxis(0).yAxis(0).zoom(-75)
                .signatureFieldName("ApplicantSignature");
        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();
        signatureProperties.signerName("name").signerLocation("location")
                .signatureReason("Security").preferredSize(0).page(3)
                .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                .buildSignature();
```

This is where I want the signature to go on the third page.
[image: This is where I want the signature to go on the third page.]

This is where it is going on the first page.
[image: This is where it is going on the first page.]

These are the field names in the form.
[image: This shows the field names.]

Comment: Is [this (http://www.ors.od.nih.gov/ser/dpsac/bgchecks/Documents/hhs-745.pdf)](http://www.ors.od.nih.gov/ser/dpsac/bgchecks/Documents/hhs-745.pdf) your form? If it is, then **A** the signature field for the applicant signature has the name `topmostSubform[0].Page3[0].SignatureField1[0]`, not `ApplicantSignature`, and **B** the form is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA form which may complicate things a bit. If it is not, though, please supply your version of the form for analysis and reproduction of the issue.

Comment: @mkl if he really wants to sign THAT document then it won't work with PDFBox at all. That document has /UR3 permissions, which we don't support. The document does get signed, but an error message comes that the extended properties are lost.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm afraid there is more broken in the code creating the visible signature. The OP especially uses `signatureFieldName("ApplicantSignature")`hoping that this will set the name (**T** value) of the signature form field. In the code I only see that the value is used to set the name (**Name** value) in some signature dictionary. Furthermore I don't see any code for using an existing empty signature form field; but I think that is exactly what the OP wants to do, sign the empty signature field he assumes to have the name `ApplicantSignature`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I assume simply removing the **UR3** usage rights signature would be acceptable for the OP. The issue mentioned above, though, might be a show-stopper.

Comment: @mkl I won't touch that signature code, except for small bugfixes and refactoring - it is a real labyrinth to me :-( Denis: maybe open an issue in JIRA and attach that file. But there no guarantee it will be fixed quickly, some bugs are fixed in an hour, but I've also seen a simple one that took 10 years.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *it is a real labyrinth to me* - I have to agree. I wiggled myself through the code in debug mode but I consider the architecture unfathomable.

Comment: @DenisMP Which version of pdfbox you were using?

Answer (score 1):

See this line in CreateVisibleSignature.java, in signPDF()  (not included in your question, but part of the example code in PDFBox you mention):

```
// options.setPage(signatureProperties.getPage());
```

remove the "//" and the signature appears on page 3.

Re position, change this part of your code

```
xAxis(0).yAxis(0)
```

to other coordinates, e.g. these:

```
xAxis(100).yAxis(715)
```

Now about the question which code in the question is correct - the last one is:

```
PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(args[2], image, 3);
visibleSig.xAxis(0).yAxis(0).zoom(-75).signatureFieldName("ApplicantSignature");
PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();
signatureProperties.signerName("name").signerLocation("location")
    .signatureReason("Security").preferredSize(0).page(3)
    .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
    .buildSignature();
```

The 3 in PDVisibleSignDesigner is to choose the size of the page. The second 3 is to store the number of the page for later. The page numbers are 1-based here.

Comment: Thank you and mkl for all you comments.  I have a question about the other page args:  What value should I use for PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(
                args[2], image, 3);.  I have 3.  What value should I user for signatureProperties.signerName("name").signerLocation("location")
                .signatureReason("Security").preferredSize(0).page(3)
                .visualSignEnabled(true).setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                .buildSignature(); I have 3 as well.

Comment: @DenisMP use 3 for both. The first (PDVisibleSignDesigner) is to decide the size of the page. The second is the page number. I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you Tilman.  I am going to post an answer based on what I have learned.  Please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the page settings given to me by the folks that responded to my question I am posting an answer base on my current knowledge of how signatures work in pdfbox.

First of all, the pre-existing form that I am working with, at least from a pdfbox perspective, seems to only have one page it in.  When I use adobe DC pro to show the coordinates, it only shows the coordinates up to about the middle of the second page.  So even though I set the X,Y coordinates to 100, 715, the signature image appears on the bottom of the first page, not on the 3rd.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe that pdfbox only allows you sign the entire document and not individual signature fields that already exist in the document.  Pre-existing signature fields are not affected by pdfbox as pdfbox appears not to be able to reference them.

If you bring up the pdf on adobe dc pro and click on the Signature Panel, you can see that the pdf was signed by pdfbox, but the pre-existing signature fields still indicate that they need to be signed.

I am guessing at this point that pdfbox adds the signatures that it signs to the pre-existing document.

I also noticed that the pdfbox signatures are invisible, even though the "who", "location", "reason", and date have been set, and that the image that you place in the the signature that pdfbox signs is the only thing that is actually visible in the resulting output pdf.  If there is no image, then hard copy print outs don't show that the document is signed.

Again, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: **A** If you don't have a solution but merely an interim report, please edit your question and append that information there. Answers are meant for solutions. **B** *"I believe that pdfbox only allows you sign the entire document "* - strictly speaking PDF signatures always sign the whole document revision. This is different for genuine XFA signatures, but the XFA specification is not part of the PDF standard.

Comment: **C** *"not individual signature fields that already exist in the document"* - indeed, it really looks like the PDFBox code for creating visible PDF signatures does ignore existing signature fields. But signature fields only are where signatures are located and visualized, the *digital signature* underneath still signs the whole revision. **D** *"I also noticed that the pdfbox signatures are invisible..."* - you mistake the *appearance* of a signature and the actual *digital signature* underneath. The digital signature never is visible. ...

Comment: ... But signing software can add a visible appearance on the PDF, and different signing softwares put different information into this visualization. But one never should trust the information in such a visualization, there is no guarantee it is true, one should always inspect the signature properties to retrieve final information. **E** *"hard copy print outs don't show that the document is signed"* - hard copies never contain reliable information concerning PDF signatures. They may show something looking like an Adobe signature appearance which actually was not backed by a digital signature.

Comment: The real problem is that your question included three questions, I spotted the first two but not the third. While the answers to the first two may help somebody, they won't help you because the third question (as spotted by mkl) shows that it is all different. And the sad thing is that at this time, PDFBox just can't do what you need. You might try to briing it on the user mailing list, maybe our signature guy is interested (but he's not always there).

Comment: Thank you mkl and Tilman for your diligence and your time.  I appreciate your help and comments.  I apologize for stating an answer.  I will try to be better about my posts.  As Tilman suggested, it doesn't look like PDFBox can do what I need.