# PDFBox: reference existing signature (field) when signing

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to figure out whether PDFBox supports signing of existing (emtpy) signature form fields. I checked the [examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignature.java) provided however all only seem to add new fields. There was another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571055/how-can-i-get-pdvisiblesigproperties-to-write-the-signature-on-the-3-page-into-t) where the OP states:

> "Pre-existing signature fields are not affected by pdfbox as pdfbox
>   appears not to be able to reference them."

Then however this has been written a year ago and there seems to be some [effort](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3017) on the signature functionality.
So can anyone tell me the if it is possible (if so how) to reference existings signature fields? Or maybe it is planned?

**Update**
I implemented as you suggested the following functionality:

```
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
PDField field = acroForm.getField("exampleSignature");
PDSignature signature = ((PDSignatureField)field).getSignature();
```

However signature is alway `null`. After checking the PDF spec it perfectly makes sense, since empty signature fields never have the signature dictionary set. When adding a signature dictionary e.g. the values for the filter, Contents, ByteRange etc. must be filled but can only be filled with meaningfull values to the time of signing...

Comment: The other issue had that /UR3 problem. I had a look at the signature code (I'm better than a year ago) It might be possible (I haven't tested it yet), if you can get the PDSignature object from your PDF signature field with `field.getSignature()`. Are you able to do that? Can you share your PDF?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3525

Comment: I implented it as suggested however there is no `field.getSignature();` method. Code: `PDField field = acroForm.getField("existingSignature");
PDSignature signature = field.getSignature();`

Comment: Then you'd have to share the PDF or have a look yourself with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Just realized that I have to cast to `((PDSignatureField)field).getSignature()` first to get the `getSignature()`method...

Comment: See my update. Regarding the document: I can provide a test document however I only created one with acrobat. Just an empty page with one signature form field. If you don't have such an PDF (which I doubt) I can send you one...

Comment: I have one but I created it myself, not with Acrobat. So I'd prefer getting one that you created with Acrobat. (For mine, I did create an empty signature) The problem is that the PDFBox code as it is now, checks for an existing signature field so the new sample code will have to create one.

Comment: I finished my code change mentioned in the issue. Please get a snapshot at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/ (might take a few hours until it is there) and test it. If it works, I'll write a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with 2.0.4, but already in the [snapshot builds](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.4-SNAPSHOT/), it is possible to sign existing (empty) signature form fields. (It will not work with 2.0.3, even if you use the updated code example from upcoming 2.0.4, because the library code had several bugs that have been fixed). The example code can be found [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java?view=markup&sortby=date). Two things are new in the example code:

- `visibleSignatureProperties.buildSignature();` has been moved
- a call `signature = findExistingSignature(doc, "Signature1");` has been added.

What this does is to search for the signature field named "Signature1", and if found, it creates a signature dictionary (the `/V` component). Because this signature object is passed to the `doc.addSignature()` call, PDFBox will be able to detect that the parent field already exists and won't create a new one.

More details can be found in [PDFBOX-3525](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3525).